# Prove that there are 2^c measurable sets in every interval.

Tags: measure-theory, cardinals, borel-measures

the measurable sets in an interval is a subset of the power set of R. therefore its cardinality is less or equal 2^c.
I tried to prove that it is bigger or equal ot 2^c but I couldn't.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: There is an uncountable set $E$ of measure $0$ inside the interval and every subset of $E$ is measurable.

Comment: how do we know that there is an uncountable set E
 of measure 0 inside the interval ?

Comment: @elif cantor set

Comment: More precisely, within every (nondegenerate) interval there is a measure $0$ set of cardinality $c$ (not just an uncountable measure $0$ set).

Comment: cantor set is in [0,1], Can we generalize it to any other interval?

Comment: The same type of construction used to obtain the middle thirds Cantor set (or any of the various other types of Cantor sets, such as those with positive Lebesgue measure) can be carried out in any interval. Or you can appropriately translate and scale the usual middle thirds Cantor set to get its analogous version in any given interval.

Comment: Thank you so much